# Modifying one index of multidementional array causes every other child array to mutate?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

So, I've initialized a multidimensional array like this.

```
let arr = new Array(5).fill(new Array(5).fill(0));
```

doing

```
arr[2][3] = 1;
```

Will give us

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Why is this? I would guess it's a pass by reference issue and that's just a single array with references in each subsequent index, but I'm creating a new one, so why does this happen?

```js
let arr = new Array(5).fill(new Array(5).fill(0));
arr[2][3] = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: You're not creating a new one for each index. You created one array and passed it as the argument to `fill()`.

Comment: Because your fill is filling with the same instance..

Comment: You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) :`let arr = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => new Array(5).fill(0));` to pass a function to create a new copy of array each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are filling the top level array with same instance of nested array. The function `fill()` only fills the array with the same instance 5 times.

You could change to the following. By calling `map()` you ensure the nested array creation calls 5 times.

```js
let arr = new Array(5).fill(0).map(_ => new Array(5).fill(0));
arr[2][3] = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

`new Array(5).fill(0)` just creates one array that's filled with zeroes. You then fill the outer array with 5 references to that same array.

You can see what's happening more easily if you write the equivalent code:

```
let row = new Array(5).fill(0);
arr = new Array(5).fill(row);
```

There's just one `row` array, and you fill `arr` with references to it.

You need to use a loop so you create a new array for each row.

```
arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr.push(new Array(5).fill(0))
}
```

Comment: Oh, guess I didn't understand how the fill works, okay thank you.

Comment: JavaScript never creates copies of things unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind the correct way is:

```js
let arr = Array.from(Array(5),x=>Array.from(Array(5),y=>0))

arr[2][3] = 1;

arr.forEach((row,idx)=> console.log('idx>',idx, JSON.stringify(row)) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```