# Problem with pushing element to two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I create a two-dimensional array like this:

```
array = new Array(3).fill([])
```

result is array like this `[[], [], []]`

Now I want to add element to have array like this `[['new'], [], []]`.
I thought that `array[0].push('new')`
will do this, but instead it's result is: `[['new'], ['new'], ['new']]`

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Using `fill()` this way fills the array with references to a single array, not multiple arrays. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#description): *'If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.'*

Comment: Also: [Modifying one index of multidementional array causes every other child array to mutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381748/modifying-one-index-of-multidementional-array-causes-every-other-child-array-to) See: [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript) for options to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, @pilchard, it's all clear now. I initialized it with the loop and it works. Thanks.