# Why is this value updating on each array inside my 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2d array:

```js
let arr = [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

When I try to update the 1st sub array in the 2nd position with:

```js
arr[0][1] = 4
```

The output is:

```
[ [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 4, 0, 0 ] ]
```

Why are all of the sub arrays updating?

The full code is:

```js
let arr = [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
arr[0][1] = 4
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Using the snippet of your code, it is working.

Comment: you probably have referenced the same array over all places

Comment: Strange! Thanks for the 2nd set of eyes.

Comment: Duplicate: [Modifying one index of multidementional array causes every other child array to mutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381748/modifying-one-index-of-multidementional-array-causes-every-other-child-array-to). For 13 years of answers of how to avoid the problem see: [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely created the array wrongly. Your 2d array has as it's elements a reference to the same array 4 times.

Here is an example:

```js
const array2d = new Array(4).fill([0,0,0,0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array2d));
array2d[1][1] = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2d));
```

While the array is of length 4, each of its members is replaced with the same array.
On the other hand, mapping it instead would give a different result:

```js
const array2d = Array.from({length: 4}, () => [0,0,0,0])

console.log(JSON.stringify(array2d));
array2d[1][1] = 1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2d));
```